# could anyone explain behavior of the 'static int i' variable?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    static int i=5;
    if(--i){
               main();
        printf("%d ",i);
    }  
}
```

Output: 0 0 0 0
Here loop executing 5 times.After that it reaches to '0'.The control should come out of the loop.but its printing '0' four times.

Comment: Step through the code with a debugger.